# Ebook to read malayalam books

Tags: ebook-readers, android

I recently downloaded a Malayalam eBook, but I can't read it in my eBook reader on my Android (4.4.4 KitKat, Moto g) phone. Can someone suggest a reader in which I can read all languages?

Comment: We'll need to know what type of phone you have in order to recommend software.

Comment: I am using an android phone. Moto g. Android version 4.4.4 Kitkat

Comment: MotoG is just a brand-name, he is probably looking for specs. If you can share the model name.number it will be easy to know the details and answer better.